# Overriding abstract method with the inherited class as parameter type

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    ...

    public abstract void MyMethod<T>(T value);
}
```

In the inherited classes I want to pass the type of the class itself as the parameter T, so I tried to do this:

```
public class InheritedClass: BaseClass
{
    ...

    public override void MyMethod<InheritedClass>(InheritedClass value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But intellisense is warning me that 'Type parameter InheritedClass hides class Inherited class'

What does this message exactly mean? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You'd need to define the generic type on the base class instead of on the method in order to do that.  You cannot set the generic type on a method when defining it, just when calling it.

Comment: 'Type parameter InheritedClass hides class Inherited class' means that it interprets it as a NEW method. Since it is with the same name it is warning you that you "HIDE" the method in the base class.

Comment: @st_stefanov No, it's not hiding the method it's overriding it.  The error is because it's defining a generic type that has the same name as the class.

Comment: Hm, right...Not sure if in C# such syntax is possible (base InheritedClass value), but could lead you in the right direction. Sorry, could not help more.

Comment: You said, *"In the inherited classes I want to pass the type of the class itself as the parameter T"* What are you really trying to do here, though? Do you want a version of the method that works differently if type `T` is called with the same class? Or are you trying to force clients to only use a specific type with the generic method? Or something else?

Comment: Where is your abstract method called from ? What do you do with its return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your method is creating a generic type with the same name as the class. You cannot specify the generic type for a method when defining it, only when calling it.

Only way to achieve that is to define the generic type on the class so you can specify it when you inherit.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract void MyMethod(T value);
}

public class InheritedClass: BaseClass<InheritedClass>
{
    public override void MyMethod(InheritedClass value)
    {
    }
}
```